# What are these different outputs, when try to access an array with different format specifiers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I know that `&` is used to get the memory address of a variable.
I tried to access an array with different format specifiers. But instead getting an error it prints different outputs. I don't know what are these outputs or what's happening there.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int y[] = (12, 56, 7, 78};

    printf(" 1 %d\n", y);
    printf(" 2 %s\n", y);
    printf(" 3 %f\n", y);
    printf(" 4 %p\n", y);
    printf(" 5 %d\n", &y);
    printf(" 6 %p\n", &y);
    printf(" 7 %d\n", y[0]); 
    printf(" 8 %p\n", y[0]);
    printf(" 9 %d\n", &y[0]);
    printf(" 10 %p\n", &y[0]);

}
```

The output is,

```
1  425720416
2

3 0.000000
4 00000098195ffa60
5 425720416
6 00000098195ffa60
7 12
8 000000000000000c
9 425720416
10 00000098195ffa60
```

An another output,

```
1 -853543088
2

3 0.000000
4 0000009fcd1ff750
5 -853543088
6 0000009fcd1ff750
7 12
8 000000000000000c
9 -853543088
10 0000009fcd1ff750
```

It prints minor numbers also.

I know these values changes in different executions. I need to what are these outputs. In number 2 the output is empty two lines. Only the thing I know here is the memory address which is a hex value, and the value of the array element.

Can somebody explain this.I'm on a windows 10 os and compiler is mingw.

Comment: Please don't undelete some old question and edit it to ask something completely different. If you have a new question, post it using "ask question", not by completely changing some old post.

Comment: New questions are not accepting from my account. It says improve my previous questions which are mostly duplicated and answered by many prople. I don't know a better way to make them perfect.

Comment: Well this isn't how... when asking a question, post the _actual_ code which you are compiling and running, not something you have written down just now without trying.

Comment: If new questions are not being accepted from your account -- that is, you are presently under a question ban -- then it is *especially* wrong to try to slip in a new question through the back door. And inasmuch as it is likely to attract downvotes and close votes (particularly if the questions aren't any better quality than your previous ones), it is probably counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an argument whose type does not match the expected type of the format specifier, you get *Undefined Behavior* -- that is, just about anything (or nothing) might be output or it might crash or do something else weird.

The only lines that don't have this problem are 4,6,7, and 10 -- 7 is passing an int to `%d`, so prints it as expected, and the rest are passing a pointer to `%p` so it prints the pointer value in a vaguely readable way.  They're all actually passing the same pointer, so it prints the same way (the only difference being the pointer's target type)